# Precise clicking with overlapping divs

Tags: css, html, trim, clicking

I'm sorry if the title doesn't explain it well enough, but it's the best title i could think of to represent my question.

So I've got two divs:

```
.div-arrow
{
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
    display:block;
    width: 136px;
    height: 54px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: url(ImagePathHere) no-repeat scroll 0px 0px transparent;
    zoom: 50%;
}

.div-diamond
{
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    width: 83px;
    height: 54px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: url(ImagePathHere) no-repeat scroll -272px 0px transparent;
    zoom: 50%;
}
```

And I use them to make a layout like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/htFRd.png

Clicking where the red mark is will activate the green diamond, instead of the diamond it looks like you're clicking.  I was wondering how I go about trimming those unseen sections of the image/div, so that you actually click the divs it looks like you're clicking.

Comment: Have you considered an image map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All elements on a web page are essentially blocks - so although you may create the look of a circle or a diamond etc it's still really a four sided block element.

For your problem you could consider either using an image map:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/objects.html

Or possibly using the HTML5 CANVAS method:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas

Comment: I've looked into using both a canvas and an image map, and went with the image map as it seemed to be more what i was looking for.  The original issue where the wrong diamond would be activated is no longer there, but there is still the issue of it not activating the proper diamond.  using the same example from my original question, clicking the red spot activates neither diamond, and I believe it to be an over lapping issue, since there is still areas around each diamond that are transparent but considered part of the image.(1/2)

Comment: is there a better way to get it to identify what it's supposed to click, or is my best option adding an area in each map for each transparent zone to activate what it looks like it should activate?(2/2)

Comment: I can only think you're not setting up the image map as well as you could be. What are you using to create the image map? I'd recommend dreamweaver and you should be able to map each part of the image exactly as you want it.

Comment: I've been doing in in the code like `<map id="map"><area ...></map>`, i'll check out dreamweaver and see if it helps